# M# icon disappeared when updating

Tags: m#

I clicked 'update' on the 'check for updates' page in M# and then the program turned off and the icon disappeared. How do I fix this?

The version I have was 4.5.776 and then I clicked update.

Comment: In what? Visual Studio? What version do you have now?

Comment: If visual studio was not open, it may have already updated it for you. Check to see if the m# icon is on your desktop and check the version, you should see it has been updated to which ever is the latest version.

Comment: The icon isn't anywhere on the desktop. I had it pinned to my taskbar and it disappeared from there.